# Can't run any java applets in any browser

Tags: java, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, applet

I can't seem to run a single applet with java. I have the newest software installed on my computer but when I try to run an applet, I get a null error thrown in the console. This happens even when I try to run an applet off of Java.com to test if my plugin is working. Then if I click continue either I get an empty box saying Error or just a blank grey box. Anyone have an idea of what can be done to fix this? This is happening in all browsers.

Ok now I got it pointing correctly.

if I do:

```
java -v I get Unrecognized option: -v Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

if I do:

```
java -version I get: java -version java version "1.7.0_51" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13) Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: Could you try checking your Java version in a Command Prompt window with the command: `java -v` and pasting the output in your question?

Comment: Says java not reconized.Do I need to install something else?

Comment: Then you probably doesn't have java installed. Download java and install it again...

Comment: I did 3 times, i see it in my programs and files to be uninstalled. Do I need to manually update the environments or something?

Comment: Ok now I got it pointing correctly. if I do java -v I get 

Unrecognized option: -v
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

if I do java -version I get:

java -version
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode, sharing)